# How to enable Vsync with Kivy on OS X

Tags: python, macos, kivy, vsync

I am starting to learn Kivy and after building the tutorial Pong app, I see crazy tearing when the ball redraws, obviously because graphic updates are not in sync with the vertical refresh rate.

Is there anyway to achieve such sync?